# How to get last locator of div using Robot Framework

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, robotframework

I don't have any idea to get last locator from `div`

I try to count elements by `Get Element Count` in `div` but it got just 1

example html

```
<div class="add-product"
 <p data-aura-rendered-by="188:14729;a">
  <span data-aura-rendered-by="191:14729;a">01-January</span>
 <p data-aura-rendered-by="195:14729;a">
  <span data-aura-rendered-by="198:14729;a">02-February</span>
 <p data-aura-rendered-by="230:14729;a">
  <span data-aura-rendered-by="233:14729;a">07-July</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

I need to count all elements in `div` or get last position in `div` (07-July) but each time the `div` contains a different number of elements (it depends on test data).

Comment: `Get Element Count   xpath:*//div/p/span` should give the correct count

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following `xpath` it will identify the last element `07-July`.

```
(//div[@class='add-product']//span)[last()]
```